# Unexpected Quantifier in IE8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

IE8 is reporting an Unexpected Quantifier error, with the following JS function, which I want to use to strip certain symbols from a string.

```
function stripCurrencySymbols(currStr){
  var symbols = [",",'£',"p","$"];
  for(i in symbols){
    currStr = currStr.replace(new RegExp(symbols[i], 'g'),"");
  }
  return currStr;
}
```

I think it's because the $ needs to be escaped, I tried replacing it with \$, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, where is the comma used as a currency symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `"\\$"` when you're constructing a regex from a string.

Also, why not do this:

```
function stripCurrencySymbols(currStr){
    return currStr.replace(/[,£p$]/g, "");
}
```

`[,£p$]` is a character class meaning "one of the included characters"; inside a character class, most metacharacters like `$` need not be escaped.